# How do I show menu item hot keys?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-menu

In (insert any other OS here), many context menus items have hot keys for fast access (which are shown by underlining the appropriate character).

Is there a way to get this working on Mac? There do seem to be keys that jump to certain items, but I can't figure out what they are.

Note that I don't want to set up millions of shortcuts because

1. Applications have standard menu navigations across platforms
2. There's hundreds of items that I use in different contexts

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the "equivalent" functionality is based on the starting characters and lots of typing as explained in [Navigating to options in context menus](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52531/navigating-to-options-in-context-menus)'s answers - in that question you can see that some menu items would be diabolically hard to select, involving typing whole words to disambiguate 2 items.

It seems that the application can specify priority, since the item selected isn't necessarily the first one that starts with what is being typed.